# XMLtoDataFrame: "Duplicate subscripts for columns" When trying to load multiple files (R)

Tags: r, xml, lapply, rbind

I'm trying to load many files from a folder in R that are of the form '.xml'. The files are contained in one folder with any subfolders. I tried to get them in one shot using the following code:

```
allfiles <- list.files("MyDirectory", pattern = '*.xml', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
hope <- do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(allfiles,xmlToDataFrame))
```

Unfortunately, this is the result:

```
"Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c("12786998421436773",  : duplicate subscripts for columns'"
```

And I'm not even quite sure what the problem is? It works when I do it by individual files but there are upwards of 30,000 files so it's not really feasible. I've tried it a different way (using a for loop) but will get an error like the "xml file is not of type XML' even though the file name it outputs ends in the '.xml' tag.

Any clarity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be hard to go about this without a reproducible example. Make a small snippet of your xml file and share that, too.

Comment: Are you sure the files all have the same simple format without any duplicate or nested tags?  I would loop through the files and add some checks and a counter to see where it breaks

Comment: Just because a file ends with .xml does not make it a well-formed XML document. Also `xmlToDataframe` takes args, particularly the repeated nodes to map into columns..